# Can you set a view name for all injected ModelAndView?

Tags: spring, modelandview

I am writing a spring application and for every page I return the same view and populate it with content fragments. Does anyone know if and how to set this view name so that I do not have to set it with every controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/Login")
public ModelAndView login(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    modelAndView.setViewName("default");
    modelAndView.addObject("view", "login");
    modelAndView.addObject("title", "Login");
    modelAndView.addObject("jsNeeded", true);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This is an example of a controller. I would like to not have to repeat the

```
modelAndView.setViewName("default");
```

Comment: Define injection here. Spring creates a new instance for each method call and is treating it as a model attribute. Basically this isn't the way to do things like that. The simplest solution is to create a factory which constructs a fresh `ModelAndView` with the defaults set, in the places you need it, call this factory.

Comment: It is set up so that a ModelAndView object is injected into the method meaning it is passed in. I believe that if the object cannot be found spring essentially creates a new instance but I'm not sure if that's actually how it works.

Comment: As mentioned nothing is actually injected, there is just a new instance of `ModelAndView` for each method invocation. You only save the line `ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView()`. `ModelAndView` isn't a supported method argument for request handling methods, so it is treated as any arbitrary object and a new instance is being created, this works by the grace of a default no-arg constructor (if that wouldn't have been there it would fail).